# Implementing OR with the lc-3

Tags: beginner, assembly, lc-3

Today, something possessed me and I started learning assembly. My poison of choice is the [lc-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC-3), this is my very first program.

It is actually only the first part of a two part problem, but this already took enough that I thought it merited a review, just in case the day's insanity also expressed itself in my code.

It runs without errors, I'm fairly confident the OR logic is sound, I'd like to focus on ascertaining that I'm storing/loading effectively and in the correct locations.

The task:

> Perform an OR on two binary numbers stored in X3020 and x3021
>   Store the result at x3022

My code:

```
.ORIG x3000 ;
  LD R0, x001f  ; fetches data from x3020, stores into R0
  LD R1, x001f  ; fetches data from x3021, stores into R1

  NOT R0, R0    ; start of OR logic
  NOT R1, R1
  AND R2, R0, R1
  NOT R2, R2   ; end of OR logic

  ST R2, x001B  ; Stores result into x3022
  HALT
.END
```

Gratitude to the brave and wonderful souls who review assembly code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LD R0, x001f  ; fetches data from x3020, stores into R0
LD R1, x001f  ; fetches data from x3021, stores into R1
ST R2, x001B  ; Stores result into x3022
```

All of these instructions are correct. When the first instruction is being executed the PC is at x3001. Adding x001F to it will correctly address location x3020. When the third instruction is being executed the PC is at x3007. Adding x001B to it will address location x3022.
From the manual we learn

> Program Counter; 16-bit register that contains the memory address of the next
>   instruction to be fetched. For example, during execution of the instruction at address
>   A, the PC contains address A + 1, indicating the next instruction is contained in
>   A + 1.

and also

> Memory address space 16 bits, corresponding to 65,536 locations, each
>   containing one word (16 bits). Addresses are numbered from 0 (i.e, x0000)
>   to 65,535 (i.e., xFFFF).

Here's an alternative to your OR solution

```
NOT R1,R1
AND R0,R0,R1
NOT R1,R1
ADD R0,R0,R1
```

The less registers you use the better on the very limited architecture of the LC-3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the book, so I might only guess on the ISA details. *Usually* PC is incremented after the fetch stage, so a PC-relative address is computed with the updated PC. I would expect however that on the 16-bit architecture PC is incremented by 2, rather than by 1, so it *seems* that the load instructions should be

```
  LD R0, x001e  ; x001f is questionable
```

Same goes for store.

In any case, a sane assembler relieves the programmer from manual address calculation. *Usually*, it is possible to write (`dot` representing the instruction address for assembler)

```
 LD R0, x3020-.
```

*Edit: (hit a button a bit early)*

Better yet, use labels. Every assembler I know support syntax similar to

```
.ORIG x3020
Data1: .byte
Data2: .byte
Result: .byte
```

I bet lc-3 has something similar.

Keep in mind that PC-relative addressing is obsoleted in lc-3b.